# Javascript array.prototype.every not working inside function?

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex

All,

Please see the following code pen

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/eJNMwJ

I am trying to pass an array of strings into my function called Validate email which iteratively checks over emails to see if they match the regex.

However this function does not seem to work for some reason.

The regex is correct

```
    var validEmail = /^([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*)@((?:[\w-]+\.)*\w[\w-]{0,66})\.([a-z]{2,6}(?:\.[a-z]{2})?)$/i;

function validEmailList(emails) {
                console.log("running test 2");
        return emails.every(function (email) {
            validEmail.test(email.trim());
        });
    };

    emails = ['bob@bob.com', 'foobar@bob.com'];
    $('.test1').append(validEmail.test("foobar@foo.com"));
    $('.test2').append(validEmailList(emails));
```

Nothing seems to be returned from the function, I am expecting a boolean.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The function you pass to `every` also has to `return` something.

```
function validEmailList(emails) {
            console.log("running test 2");
    return emails.every(function (email) {
        return validEmail.test(email.trim());
    });
};
```

Although if you use arrow syntax, the `return` is implied:

```
function validEmailList(emails) {
    return emails.every( email => validEmail.test(email.trim()) );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The call back called by `Array.prototype.every` needs to return a boolean value:

```
return emails.every(function (email) {
  return validEmail.test(email.trim());
//^^^^^^^
});
```